# BindingContext is null during MvxAdapter creation

Tags: android, xamarin.android, mvvmcross

I'm running the following code in an Android view.

```
protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
{
    var autoComplete = this.FindViewById<MvxAutoCompleteTextView>(Resource.Id.AutoComplete);
    autoComplete.Adapter = new MvxFilteringAdapter(this);
}
```

It is failing when trying to create a new `MvxFilteringAdapter` with:

> bindingContext is null during MvxAdapter creation - Adapter's should only be created when a specific binding context has been placed on the stack

I'm trying to understand why the binding context is null and how to resolve it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to call `base.OnCreate()` otherwise you are not telling MvvmCross to create a ViewModel.